# Error using map_fn to decode jpgs into tensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am using tensorflow serving with batch processing for a neural network. I am basing my code in the [example of the inception network](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/example): I want to do the decoded and preprocessing of the images in the graph, so I have modified the [exporting script](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_export.py) in order to preprocess the images using a map function:

```
...
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # Build inference model.
    jpegs = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(None))
    images = tf.map_fn(lambda jpeg : image_processing.image_preprocessing(jpeg, False), jpegs,
                       dtype=tf.float32, back_prop=False)

    # Run inference.
    logits, _ = inception_model.inference(images, len(labels_names))
 ...
```

[image_preprocessing](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f8cc1ea5447eb2cff42fb72e6132b1c6d58d0b2c/inception/inception/image_processing.py) is the same as it can be found in the inception model. It received a encoded image in bytes and returns a tensor of float values with the image decoded, scaled and preprocessed.

The model is exported correctly but when I test it in tensorflow serving I receive the following error:

> grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.NetworkError: NetworkError(code=StatusCode.INTERNAL, details="Output 0 of type
>   string does not match declared output type float for node
>   _recv_map/TensorArrayPack_0 = _Recvclient_terminated=true, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=6080232697619483985,
>   tensor_name="map/TensorArrayPack:0", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"")

Oputput type should be a tensor of floats as it is in image_preprocessing but it says it is a string. What is wrong? (image_preprocessing works without any problems in other parts of the code so I think I am doing something wrong in those lines)

Comment: What do you feed in `jpegs`? Is `None` the correct shape? When looking at the code of Inception, I found that `jpegs` should be a **JPEG encoded string Tensor**, of size `[batch_size]`.

Comment: In the jpgs the bytes of the jpg are passed. None is the correct shape as I am exporting the model for tensorflow-serving. You can see the code of the example with only one jpg as input: [server](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_inference.cc) & [client](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py). And some comments about how to change it to work it with batch processing of images: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/38